# Topological Invariants for Group

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, big-list

Let $\mathbf{Grp}$ be the category of groups and $\mathbf{Top}$ be the category of topological spaces.  To each group $(G, \circ_G)$, we can associate a topological space $(G,\tau_G)$ the basis for this topology being given by the set of all subgroups of $G$. Call this topology on $G$ to  be its **Subgroup Topology** Thus we get a functor $\mathscr{F}:\mathbf{Grp}\to\mathbf{Top}$ which associates a given group to its. Also note that any homomorphism $f:(G,\circ_G)\to (H,\circ_H)$ induces a continuous function between the corresponding **Subgroup Topological Spaces**.

This process looks like a sort of "inverse process" to what we do in Algebraic Topology especially when we try to associate the Fundamental Group to a given topological space. In Algebraic Topology in general, we are trying to find algebraic invariants of a given topological space whereas here I am trying to find topological invariants for a group.

However, it is clear that the functor which I have defined above is just an example of a functor from  $\mathbf{Grp}$ to  $\mathbf{Top}$ and (I believe) is not going to be much useful.

So my question is,

> Does there exist any useful topological invariant of a group? More specifically, given any group can we associate a topological space to it (in the same way we did for Fundamental Groups)? If so can some literature be mentioned?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space

Comment: @YCor: But $G$ may not be a topological group in general.

Comment: Every group is a topological group with the discrete topology. The classifying space is already very interesting for discrete groups.

Comment: In particular, group cohomology can be seen as a topological invariant of a group. Although it has a purely algebraic definition, it is naturally isomorphic to the cohomology of the corresponding classifying space.

Comment: By extensive searching, I found [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82671574.pdf) which seems relevant.

Comment: The link points to a 1977 paper on the verbal topology by R. Bryant. This is an instance of a group topology (= topology making $G$ a topological group). There are many natural group topologies one can put on a group, such as profinite, etc, which can be trivial or not according to cases. The question seems a bit open-ended at this point...

Comment: There is of course the classifying space; and if $G$ is abelian all the Eilenberg-McLane spaces $K(G,n)$ for $n\geq 2$. There are also a bunch of posets that are associated functorially to a group, and that can be geometrically realized, thus yielding topological spaces. Also following YCor's suggestion of group cohomology, there is the variety of the trivial module which is a topological space

Comment: @Max: "There are also a bunch of posets that are associated functorially to a group, and that can be geometrically realized, thus yielding topological spaces." - would you mind to give me some examples of such posets? For example, one easy example that I can think of is the Subgroup Lattice of a group.

Comment: There's the subgroup lattice but it's not super interesting precisely because it's a lattice (so its geometric realization is contractible); but for instance there's the poset of  nontrivial $p$-subgroups, the poset of nontrivial elementary abelian $p$-subgroups, whose homotopy properties are studied in a paper of Quillen

Comment: I see. Also are any of these functors full (and hopefully faithful) @Max?

Comment: no, definitely not faithful or full for these posets. The classifying space functor is almost full and faithful on discrete groups, in that the pointed homotopy classes of maps $BG\to BH$ correspond to maps $G\to H$

Answer (score 2):

For any Lie group $G$, there is a topological invariant of groups $\Gamma$ called the *$G$-character variety of $\Gamma$*.  It is defined by: $$\mathfrak{X}_G(\Gamma):=\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma,G)^*/G,$$
where $\Gamma$ is given the discrete topology, $\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma, G)$ the compact-open topology, $\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma, G)^*$ is the subspace of homomorphisms that have closed conjugation orbits (*polystable*), and finally $\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma,G)^*/G$ is the conjugation orbit space of $\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma, G)^*$.

If $\varphi:\Gamma^\prime\to \Gamma$ is an isomorphism, then for every polystable $\rho:\Gamma\to G$, then $\rho\circ \varphi$ is polystable and so defines a point $[\rho\circ \varphi]\in \mathfrak{X}_G(\Gamma^\prime)$.  This map is invertible since $\varphi$ has an inverse.  Hence, it is a topological invariant of the group.

One can think of $\mathfrak{X}_G(\Gamma)$ as a moduli space of subgroups of $G$ arising as the homomorphic image of a fixed group-type $\Gamma$.

This invariant of $\Gamma$ has applications to many areas of mathematics and mathematical physics (usually where $\Gamma$ is finitely generated).  If you google "character variety", or do a search in arXiv or MathSciNet (if you have access) you will find many research papers on the topic.

Comment: Actually an even better invariant is $\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma,G)$ without taking the quotient (but endowed with the conjugation action of $G$).